# Keeping track of online users and the pages (without mysql?)

Tags: php, mysql

I needed to track online visitors so I create a MySQL table - `online_users` having fields;

```
id (primary key), user_name, last_activity (DATETIME), page_url
```

On every page load a script inserts a new row into this table and stores relevant information.

It all works fine but this table is filling up fast (about 6k inserts daily). It doesn't do any inserts if a visitor is not logged in.

At the moment, I am manually deleting the records older than 2 weeks (and I can setup a cron job to do this job and it will not let the table size grow too large). Also, the idea of these many inserts doesn't look too good to me so I am looking to replace it but lost a bit. Can you suggest anything better, please? I have a Windows server.

Comment: Rather than `INSERT` a record, add `last_activity` and `last_page_url` to the `users` table and just `UPDATE` it every time?

Comment: It may also be easier to solution if you told us what you are using this information for? Is it just an audit of all activity; do you really need to track it for all pages?

Comment: yes, I have been thinking of doing updates when a user_id already exists. this will certainly keep the table size limited to the number of users. I intend to use this information for audit purpose + offer live support when users are actually browsing the website. I can see which page they are on etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use google analytics would be the obvious choice:
http://www.googleanalytics.com

Comment: well - as I mentioned I need to track only logged in users with their user_id, username etc and list them on a page for admin monitoring purposes while they are online ... so not very keen on using google analytics...

Comment: If you have access to their ID, you could set it as a custom variable in analytics then use their API to get the information you need.

I only suggest analytics so strongly as it circumvents your storage issues nicely.

Comment: which API you're referring to? GAPI?

Comment: Yes: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

But depending on what you want, you might find a solution like this:
http://oocharts.org quicker and easier to setup

Comment: I already use that but for different purposes. I'll think about it and see if it's the best option. thx

Comment: One more thing, you could keep a single row per user, then hold the last three (or however many is appropriate) pages they viewed in a JSON or serialized array in the table. Then update this as they move through the site?